# NSTimer Not Performing Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I am working on an app that requires a lot of user input. Because of this, I am trying to build a feature in that does not allow the user to post more information for at least 10 seconds. This would help to cut down on spammers/trolls/etc. Essentially what happens is when the user want to report something, my application measures the distance between the user and the closest other report location. If they are further than 200 Meters and haven't reported in the last 10 seconds then they are free to post. Here is come code to accomplish this:

```
if( distance > 200 && canPost){
        MainMap.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
        canPost = false
        sendTheData(String(locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude), latitude: String(locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude), time: getTime(), userId: "admin")
        let myTimer : NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(MapViewController.postDelayTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        myTimer.fire()


    }else if(distance < 200 && canPost){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Whoa There!", message: "tOO clOSE!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

And so on for the other different instances. The function called from the timer, `postDelayTimer` is this:

```
func postDelayTimer() {
    canPost = true
}
```

Pretty simple, but I am just missing something in here obviously. Does anybody have an idea? Thanks all!

What I expected to happen was the user to be unable to post again after immediately posting, but instead they are able to post continuously. It is as if the `bool canPost` always remains true.

Comment: What is the problem? Please explain what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.  (Also, why are you calling `myTimer.fire()` yourself, instead of waiting for the timer to fire on its own after 10 seconds?)

Comment: Updated, not quite sure what's causing it. Also, I do not want the timer to fire 10 seconds AFTER they report, I only want it to fire WHEN they report and be effective for the preceding 10 seconds

Comment: You initialize the timer inside a method, try and init the timer in the class and start it in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by calling the function after the button was pressed.Inside of this function was an `NSTimer` which, when fired, proceeded to call a third function in charge of charing the required booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
    let myTimer : NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(MapViewController.postDelayTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    myTimer.fire()
```

The second line is incorrect, so remove it. You do not want to manually fire the timer. You want to wait for the timer to fire on its own, after 10 seconds have elapsed.

Comment: Ok, second line gone. What I am trying is to call the function directly from the button, which has the timer script inside. After the 10 seconds it'll fire to change the variable in another function. That's the best I have for right now

Comment: When I remove the `fire()` line it throws an error an complains that `Initialization of immutable value myTimer was never used;` How can I fix this?

Comment: You can either save it in an instance variable as in Idan's answer, or just remove the `let myTimer : NSTimer = ` part. You only need to keep a reference to the timer if you might want to invalidate it later.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You create the timer inside the a method init the timer as a class variable and use it globally. Something like:

   ```
   class MapViewController: UIViewController {
       var myTimer = NSTimer()

       func activateTimer() {
         myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target:self, selector: #MapViewController.postDelayTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
       }
   }
   ```
2. `myTimer.fire()` is unnecessary. The timer will fire once set.

Comment: Is it okay to have the warning `Variable myTimer was written to but never read`?

Comment: Do you have a spot where you `invalidate` the timer?

Comment: No, no need to as it doesn't repeat.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Seems you got it, all the best!